# JavaScript timer won't reset

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I really need some help with my Javascript countdown timer.
I am trying to make a countdown timer, for a quiz game, that resets and starts over when a button is pressed.

I can get it to reset and start over but if I press the button before time gets to 0, it will count down super fast.

Can anyone help? Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var countdown;
var time;

function init() {
    time = 11;
    reset();
    trigger();

}

function trigger() {

    if(time > 0) {
        time--;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time;
        if(time > 0) {
            countdown = setTimeout('trigger()', 1000);
        }
    }
}

function reset() {

    clearTimeout(trigger);

}

</script>

<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="init()" />

<h3 id="timer">10</h3>
```

Of course I have the basic HTML document set up. The script is inside the  tags and there's no difference in timer behavior if I place the script in  element.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2wu73ba0/ works fine here

Comment: No it doesn't naeem, I just add another interval. try pressing it at 8,6,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing the timeout in the reset. it should be

```
 clearTimeout(countdown);
```

like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wu73ba0/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been coding all day and I think my brain won't work properly anymore :D maybe I should take a break

Comment: No probs regniscire, Things become blurry after looking at the screen too long. take a break.